# Remap values in pandas column with a dict, None if KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'd like to modify the col1 of the following dataframe df:

```
        col1        col2
0       Black       7
1       Death       2
2       Hardcore    6
3       Grindcore   1
4       Deathcore   4
...
```

I want to use a dict named `cat_dic={'Black':'B', 'Death':'D', 'Hardcore':'H'}` to get the following dataframe:

```
        col1        col2
0       B           7
1       D           2
2       H           6
3       None        1
4       None        4
...
```

I know I can use `df.map` or `df.replace`, for example like this:

```
df.replace({"col1":cat_dic})
```

but I want the KeyErrors of the dictionnary to return None, and with the previous line, I got this result instead:

```
        col1        col2
0       B           7
1       D           2
2       H           6
3       Grindcore   1
4       Deathcore   4
...
```

Given that Grindcore and Deathcore are not the only 2 values in col1 that I want to be set to None, have you got any idea on how to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dict.get`:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].map(lambda x: cat_dic.get(x, None))
#default value is None
df['col1'] = df['col1'].map(cat_dic.get)

print (df)
   col1  col2
0     B     7
1     D     2
2     H     6
3  None     1
4  None     4
```

Performance comparison in 50k rows:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)
cat_dic={'Black':'B', 'Death':'D', 'Hardcore':'H'}

In [93]: %timeit df['col1'].map(cat_dic.get)
3.22 ms ± 16.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [94]: %timeit df.col1.apply(lambda x: None if x not in cat_dic.keys() else cat_dic[x])
15 ms ± 293 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [95]: %timeit df['col1'].replace(dict(dict.fromkeys(df['col1'].unique(), None), **cat_dic))
12.3 ms ± 409 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [96]: %timeit df.col1.apply(lambda x: None if x not in cat_dic.keys() else x)
13.8 ms ± 837 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [97]: %timeit df['col1'].map(cat_dic).replace(dict({np.nan: None}))
9.97 ms ± 1.25 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `pd.apply` first

```
df.col1 = df.col1.apply(lambda x: None if x not in cat_dic.keys() else x)
```

Then, you can safely use `pd.replace`

```
df.replace({"col1":cat_dic})
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in One line:

```
df1['col1'] = df1.col1.apply(lambda x: None if x not in cat_dic.keys() else cat_dic[x])
```

Output is:

```
   col1  col2
0     B     7
1     D     2
2     H     6
3  None     1
4  None     4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner easy solution which gives us the expected output.

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].map(cat_dic).replace(dict({np.nan: None}))
```

Output :

```
   col1  col2
0     B     7
1     D     2
2     H     6
3  None     1
4  None     4
```

Answer (score 0):

`Series.map` already maps `NaN` to the mismatched key

```py
$ print(df['col1'].map(cat_dic))

0      B
1      D
2      H
3    NaN
4    NaN
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Anyway, you can update your `cat_dic` with missing keys from `col1` column

```py
cat_dic = dict(dict.fromkeys(df['col1'].unique(), None), **cat_dic)
df['col1'] = df['col1'].replace(cat_dic)
```

```
print(cat_dic)

{'Black': 'B', 'Death': 'D', 'Hardcore': 'H', 'Grindcore': None, 'Deathcore': None}

print(df)

   col1  col2
0     B     7
1     D     2
2     H     6
3  None     1
4  None     4
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
In [6]: df.col1.map(cat_dic.get)
Out[6]: 
0       B
1       D
2       H
3    None
4    None
dtype: object
```

You could also use `apply`, both work. When working on a `Series`, `map` is faster I think.

---

###### Explanation:

You can get a default value for missing keys by using `dict.get` instead using the `[..]`-operator.  By default, this default value is `None`.  So simply passing the `dict.get` method to `apply`/`map` just works.